# Unable to Change image position from one frame to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying implement Unblock me Puzzle. i want to change image position from one frame(Block) to another Frame(Block) only when half distance of next frame is covered.

I have implemented the logic for puzzle. but unable to implement code for changing image from one frame to another.

Comment: And what is your question? Provide some code where you have stuck

Comment: -(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event]; 
    float tempX, tempY;
    float temp1, temp2, temp4, temp3, temp5, temp7, temp6, temp8;  
    
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:subView];
    
    tempX = touchLocation.x;
    tempY = touchLocation.y;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot set frame to UIImage. Set the new frame position to the image view (UIImageView) that contains the image.